# VB.net - RsData / Cleaning up code

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, code-cleanup

I have a question regarding VB.net and the use of rsData connections to an SQL database.

Basically we have a few inline pages that will display course information of courses that my institution runs. The code will connect to an SQL DB and pull through live data directly in the following format.

```
html += "<tr><td>" & rsData("M_Start") & "</td><td>" & rsData("WEEKS") & "</td><td>" &     rsData("DAYSTIME") & "</td></tr>"
```

Now I was wondering if people would suggest pulling directly from an open DB connection or map the RsData results to strings? All data connections open and close after they have done their required portions and we have around 5 different procedures that occur within the page.

I'm worried that the code isn't as clean as it could be and would really like to tidy up this inherited nightmare. Also can people shed any best practice with inline code and the multiple data connections?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to give you a full solution on how to clean-up the code without seeing it all. Better ways to display your data might be using a GridView or Repeater.

However, if you are going to build up the HTML in a String variable I'd suggest doing the portion you've posted like this:

```
Dim html As New Text.StringBuilder
html.Append(String.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>",
                                  rsData("M_Start"),
                                  rsData("WEEKS"),
                                  rsData("DAYSTIME")))
```

It makes it more readable and a StringBuilder performs better than incrementing a String variable multiple times.

I'm not sure how you are dealing with repetition, but you could then do something like this (assuming rsData belongs to a DataTable):

```
Const htmlRowFormat As String = "<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>"

Dim html As New Text.StringBuilder

For Each dr As DataRow In rsDataTable.Rows
    html.Append(String.Format(htmlRowFormat,
                                 rsDataTable("M_Start"),
                                 rsDataTable("WEEKS"),
                                 rsDataTable("DAYSTIME")))
Next
```

To get your html: `html.ToString`